# calling an api inside a foreach loop in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

In my factory I have this function which calls a delete api as following :

```
removeOffre: function(id) {
        return $http.delete('http://localhost:8080/removeOffre/'+id)
            .then(function(response) {
                return response;
            }, function(error) {
                return 'There was an error getting data';
            });
    },
```

this function works.

and then I want to delete multiple entries so I use this function for that :

```
removeSelectedItems: function(selectedItems) {
      let deleted = true;
      angular.forEach(selectedItems,function(id){
        $http.delete('http://localhost:8080/removeOffre/'+id)
          .then(function(response) {}, function() {
            deleted = false;
          });
      });
      return response;
    }
```

in the server side all entries are deleted, but in my browser console I get this error :

```
Error: response is not defined
factory.removeSelectedItems@http://localhost:9000/scripts/providers/offresFactory.js:60:7
deleteSelectedItems/$scope.ok@http://localhost:9000/scripts/controllers/offreController.js:135:5
anonymous/fn@http://localhost:9000/scripts/js/angular.min.js line 212 > Function:2:194
```

I call this function from my controller as following :

```
offresFactory.removeSelectedItems(entriesToDelete).then(function (state) {
      if(state == true) $state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true});
    }, function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

How can I solve this ?

Comment: You are returning `response` in method `removeSelectedItems` but you never define a variable named `response`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are deleting multiple items and obtain multiple responses for those. You can use Angular's `$q.all` to turn the list of result promises you create by the `$http.delete` into a result list promise which you can then return.

```
removeSelectedItems: function(selectedItems) {
    return $q.all(selectedItems.map(function(id) {
        return $http.delete('http://localhost:8080/removeOffre/' + id);
    })).then(
        function(responses) {
            return true; // all were successful 
        },
        function(error) {
            return false; // there was at least one error
        })
}
```

Your attempt with the local variable `deleted` won't work as you have to wait for the promises created by `$http.delete` to be fulfilled.